# How to enable copy-to-clipboard with zathura-pdf-poppler?

Tags: pdf, zathura

How do I make Zathura copy selected text to the system clipboard?

I'm using Zathura with the poppler PDF plugin.

Comment: ctrl/c + v doesn't work?

Comment: @peterh zathura currently supports only mouse region selection (there no support for text selection via keyboard). When a region is selected the copy operation it triggered immediately (See https://github.com/pwmt/zathura/commit/f8061febe49947a0a15db516767f23c39e96938a#diff-244ba14eb252b90c1fa72069495e4d2cR491)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Add `set selection-clipboard clipboard` in the config file `~/.config/zathura/zathurarc` or `/etc/zathurarc`.

Answer (score 6):

- There are actually two clipboards. The primary clipboard is used by
  terminal and some applications and the other clipboard is used by
  most GUI applications like MS style copy/paste.
- Zathura, by default, copies the selected contents to the Primary
  clipboard that can be accessed by middle mouse button.
- This behaviour can be changed by adding

  ```
  set selection-clipboard clipboard
  ```

  in zathura's config file at `/etc/config/zathurarc` or `~/.config/zathura/zathurarc` just as @peterh said. The selection will
  then be copied to the clipboard that can be accessed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

As @peterh said in the comment on the OP's question, When you select the text region with mouse it will be copied to your clipboard automatically

Comment: It seems to work sometimes, but it is absolutely not a given. Putting the mentioned line in the config file is the only way to ensure the behavior.